# bitbucket how to check all pull request whether i am a reviewer

Tags: bitbucket

Before last bitbucket updated, every time I wanted to check if I have any pending PR to review, it was super easy just using this link: https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/overview

Now I cannot see them. I have found [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-get-all-pull-requests-where-i-am-a-reviewer-with/qaq-p/1038292) but it is not clear to me if it is possible or not (I don't want to use any api).

I cannot believe they have removed this super useful link...

Thanks in advance